# Javalin, cannot get request body , except from HttpServlet directly

Tags: java, spring, web, javalin

i cannot get request body from Javalin's `context` object
like `context.formParam`,`context.body()`,`context.bodyAsClass()`

i've tried like this, and i can get 
request body, i use `HttpServletRequest` directly to get
request body

```
public void addPerson(Context ctx){
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            String name = ctx.req.getParameter("person_name");
            String address = ctx.req.getParameter("person_address");
            personList.add(new Person(name,address));

            map.put("status",200);
            map.put("data","Success ");
            ctx.json(map);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            map.put("status",500);
            map.put("data","Fail");

            ctx.status(500).json(map);
        }
    }
```

if i change `ctx.req.getParameter` to `ctx.formBody`
there will be error message in server's log

```
 Exception occurred while servicing http-request

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.readBytes(Ljava/io/InputStream;)[B
    at io.javalin.http.CachedRequestWrapper$cachedBytes$2.invoke(CachedRequestWrapper.kt:21) ~[javalin-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.javalin.http.CachedRequestWrapper$cachedBytes$2.invoke(CachedRequestWrapper.kt:16) ~[javalin-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
    at io.javalin.http.CachedRequestWrapper.getCachedBytes(CachedRequestWrapper.kt) ~[javalin-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.javalin.http.CachedRequestWrapper.getInputStream(CachedRequestWrapper.kt:31) ~[javalin-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.javalin.http.Context.bodyAsBytes(Context.kt:118) ~[javalin-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at io.javalin.http.Context.body(Context.kt:108) ~[javalin-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using an older version of Kotlin, you should upgrade to 1.3.X.

Comment: now i have upgraded kotlin.version in spring boot to 1.3.X
and its works. thanks

Comment: I don't use spring boot or kotlin and I'm getting this error...